# Preventing C executable from going into foreground

Tags: c, windows, gcc, taskmanager

I have made a joke program in C, on Windows, that starts in background and pops up silly windows. It was a fun project, however it raised a question/curiosity.

Here is the C code:

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    //IMPORTANT!!! You should compile this program using the -mwindows specification on GCC.

    int main(void){

      while(true){
    
        MessageBeep(MB_OK);
        MessageBox(0 , "Blip" , NULL , MB_OK);
        sleep(5);
        MessageBeep(MB_OK);
        MessageBox(0 , "Blop" , NULL , MB_OK);
        sleep(5);
        MessageBeep(MB_OK);
        MessageBox(0 , "Blup" , NULL , MB_OK);
        sleep(5);
    
      }

      return 0;


    }
```

I compiled this with GCC using the `-mwindows` option to make the executable open in background and not as a console executable. This is all fine and dandy. However, opening the *task manager* while this .exe was running I noticed that the program will stay in background while it is sleeping, but it will jump in foreground in the *task manager* when a pop up window is opened. Is there any way to prevent this? Is there any way to keep the .exe in the background as it opens pop up windows? I think it would make the program more fun.

On the same note, bonus related question, is there any way to change the name of the executable as it appears in the *task manager*? This would make the .exe even more annoying to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `MessageBox`, pass flag `MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION`. This flag doesn't do what it says it does anymore, but the code that proxies it through `csrss.exe` is still there and an application associated with a desktop can still bring up a `MessageBox` window (and nothing else) from `csrss.exe` by passing this flag.

Comment: This surely is a really clever trick! Should do the job just fine. But I wonder if there is a less tricky and more orthodox/structured way to do this.

Comment: @Noumeno: There is, you can load your code into an already-running process (not for the feint of heart).

Comment: Could you expand on this in your answer? I find this topic really interesting

Comment: @Noumeno: Do you know some assembly yet? In any case, very big.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh... I get it now. Any other way? How do programs stay in background? Like Skype?

Comment: @Noumeno: Skype launches a different program that comes into the foreground.